# Microservices error while starting up the application

Tags: java, microservices

when i start my application , facing the error as 'Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [com.deloitte.insurcloud.microservices.translator.data.naming.SqlServerNamingStrategy] as strategy [org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy]
```

not sure whether this is due to any hibernate dependency version or something else..

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [com.deloitte.insurcloud.microservices.translator.data.naming.SqlServerNamingStrategy] as strategy [org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
```

Comment: I does not recognize com.deloitte.insurcloud.microservices.translator.data.naming.SqlServerNamingStrategy How does your application.properties look like?

Comment: the properties file is configured on config server and it has the mentioned property org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy , but there is no reference of any properties in the current microservice, not sure why and where it is referring to this property.

Comment: Is it possible that the value is loaded from the config server? Because the exception happens during the context refresh

Comment: yes, I resolved the issue. the value was getting loaded from the properties file which was located at the config server. some problem was there in the properties file related to that particular value, so I corrected the file and build the whole microservice again. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Would you mind if I add my suggestion as the answer?